# Can't import a .bacpac file in Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, docker, apple-m1, azure-data-studio, azure-sql-edge

I'm running on an M1 chip, I have Azure SQL Edge in docker, and I'm trying to create a database from a .bacpac file in Azure Data Studio.
I get this error when I try:

> The sp_configure value 'contained database authentication' must be set to 1 in order to alter a contained database. You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set the value_in_use.

However, when I run:

```sql
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

I get a new error:

> Started executing query at Line 1
> Msg 15392, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 166
> The specified option 'contained database authentication' is not supported by this edition of SQL Server and cannot be changed using sp_configure.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do instead?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server 2019? What does `PRINT @@VERSION;` return?

Comment: For clarity, I suspect you aren't using 2019, you are Azure SQL Edge.

Comment: oh i apologize, yes. I'm using Azure SQL EDGE. 

Microsoft Azure SQL Edge Developer (RTM) - 15.0.2000.1574 (ARM64) 
 Jan 25 2023 10:36:08 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS aarch64) <ARM64>

Comment: And there is your answer; the error is in fact telling you the problem.

Comment: Are you saying to switch to 2019 sql server? I can't, its not supported on the M1 chip, even with docker's help unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure about that? [Regular SQL Server on Apple Silicon? Yes you can!](https://sqlblog.org/2023/03/03/sql-server-apple-silicon). If you're having problems did you check: are you still using an older version of Docker Desktop; did you forget to enable the "Use Virtualization Framework" option; did you forget to enable the "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 Emulation…" option? It won't be fast, using Rosetta, but at least it should work.

Comment: Hey @AlwaysLearning, thank you! I was reading some other sources that said that and I assumed it was true. Turns out I was mistaken. Thank you for reaffirming that. I posted the answer
thank you also @ThomA! I appreciate you guys a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I **can** install 2019 sql server in docker, despite multiple other online sources saying it's not compatible with my machine. I guess that other information was outdated and misleading,
and then I was able to run:
sp_configure and all my problems were solved.